# How to lock checkbox if cells are blank

Tags: google-sheets

How can I lock the checkbox in column A if columns B and C are blank?
I do not see a way to add custom formulas in data validation if there is a checkbox in the column.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iMYG_7JRh3SIsusbetmG6TkJhKPrqTe_pvizteOkpPs/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are willing to insert an additional column to the left of the checkboxes (such that your checkboxes are in column B and the 'condition' columns are in C & D), then you can enter the following in A2 and drag it down for as many checkboxes as needed:

```
=if(and(isblank(C2),isblank(D2)),{"",false},"")
```

Hide the column afterwards. What is happening here is that when the IF evaluates to TRUE (= both condition cells blank), it attempts to extend an array literal one cell to the right (i.e. over the top of the checkbox) with a FALSE in the checkbox. This isn't allowed (as a FALSE is already present) so generates a #REF error in A2, but has the side effect of locking the checkbox to further input (as the IF can't be TRUE if the condition cells are both blank). Type something into the condition cells and the IF then evaluates to FALSE, which does not extend an array over the checkbox (which then means it can be checked and unchecked as required).